# Can I run "image.dart" functions in background

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I want to display a loading widget while compressing the image selected.
I am using the "image.dart" package to select an image, using ImagePicker.GetImage(). 
Then I want to display a loading widget while the image is being compressed, and when it's finished display the compressed image. 
My code fundamentally works, my loading widget is cool (thanks spinkit), I can select any image, compress it and display the new one, but there is a small freeze (2-3s) while the image is being compressed. 
So I'm trying to put a loading widget to not make the user panic and tap 10 000 times to select the image wanted, but I'm not completely comfortable with asynchronous code yet.

Here's my code :

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading == true) {
      return LoadingScreen();
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[300],
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Select an image'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await getImage();
                // You can see here that I'm trying to trigger the loading widget
                setState(() {
                  loading = true;
                });
                compressImage();
                // And I want to disable the loading widget here, after the compression
                setState(() {
                  loading = false;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            pickedImage != null ? printSelectedImage() : Center(child: Text('Please select an image')),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

```
getImage() async {
    pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
}
```

```
compressImage() async {
    Img.Image selectedImage = Img.decodeJpg(File(pickedFile.path).readAsBytesSync());
    if (selectedImage.width > selectedImage.height) {
      Img.Image compressedImage = Img.copyResize(selectedImage, width: 500);
      File(pickedFile.path).writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodePng(compressedImage));
    } else {
      Img.Image compressedImage = Img.copyResize(selectedImage, height: 500);
      File(pickedFile.path).writeAsBytesSync(Img.encodePng(compressedImage));
    }

    if (pickedFile.path != null) {
      setState(() {
        pickedImage = pickedFile.path;
      });
    }
  }
```

But the result is the same, the screen is still stuck in the file selector while compressing, and then directly display the compressed image. 
I started learning dart/Flutter 2 weeks ago, so am I missing some fundamental principles of the dart language ? Am I not seeing something obvious ? 
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making something `async` doesn't move it into some magical background thread. Dart uses [isolates](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) which are basically an execution context in which dart code can run. Flutter has a single isolate which runs your app, if you do too much work in it, your app gets slow or skips frames.

You can create other isolates to do calculations and offload work and communicate between isolates by passing messages with primitive content back and forth. The drawback in Flutter is, that other isolates don't have access to Flutter plugins thus a lot of things don't work there.
There are ways to work around this but they are pretty involved.

The easiest way to start an isolate is the `compute(callback, message)` function.

> Spawn an isolate, run `callback` on that isolate, passing it `message`, and
> (eventually) return the value returned by `callback`.

I am not sure if the `image/image.dart` library uses a plugin or some other features that are not available (`dart:ui` for example), you can try offloading your image compression into the callback. If it fails with a `MissingPluginException` or something similar, then it won't work.
Remember, you can only pass primitive messages so you can not path the `pickedFile`, only the pass as argument.

For your problem however there may be an easier solution. The image picker accepts parameters for max width/height and quality. If you need the image to be encoded as PNG however then you need to create a complex solution yourself.

Comment: But does the image picker takes more time if I send him the quality that I need ?

Comment: After a quick look [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html), these primitives values that Isolates can pass to each other are either null, num, bool, double, or String. So I wouldn't be able to return all the image anyway ?

Comment: You would pick the image in the main isolate and then compress it in compute by passing the path as argument. The image picker does not take longer if you pass the size as initial argument.